# Why are array formulas not filling adjacent cells as they should?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, array

When using formula arrays with multi-cell results, the returned array is outputted in the adjacent cells as the formular arrays (as I've experienced in the past and as documented).

**Why is it that if I use an array formula with a multi-cell result, only the first cell is populated despite the formula being recognized as an array formula?**

For instance, an example is given in [the Office documentation](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) 
[with the array expanding as it should to other adjacent cells:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5DaJ.png)

```
Shares         500  300  700     450    600
Price           10   15   12.75   14     18
Total value   5000 4500 8925    6300  10800
```

In following the same example, I get:

```
Shares         500  300  700     450    600
Price           10   15   12.75   14     18
Total value   5000
```

([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaXyd.png))

I am under an Office 365 Subscription and I did try pressing simply Enter after entering the formula, with no prompt, and then Crtl+Shift+Enter. The formula in the top bar shows up as:

```
{=H30:L30*H31:L31}
```

I am kind of confused as I followed exactly several examples online. This also happened with =ROW(1:10) and so far any CSE array formula I came across.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array formula does not return array (Excel 2016)](https://superuser.com/questions/1405300/array-formula-does-not-return-array-excel-2016)

Comment: Question has been found to be a duplicate to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1405300/array-formula-does-not-return-array-excel-2016); basically the destination _array_ needs to be _selected_ (not juste the starting cell).